# Use Cases criteria

Tags: use-case

1 - I have some doubts about how to model the following problem through use cases.

Background: The company is an insurer, it is timely to an accident Car

- Story: The Actor "A" examines a new claim and determines whether the requested ACTOR "B" is to be rejected or not.
  What ACTOR "A" analyzes is whether there is financial coverage, if the driver's license is valid or if he was drunk, so the decision to request that in order to Reject the claim, by emailing ACTOR "B" referred to clear the rejection of the claim.
  On the other hand, the ACTOR "B" to give reply to the rejection, enters the system and uses a Card program with preset formats. Find the type of letter (from several), print it, and takes it to the area "Expedition" from this area to send to the customer's home.

The questions are:
Are they two use cases, ie, one for REQUEST  and one to actually REJECT, or is a single use case with two actors?
Would you represent the system sending the e-mail?
How would compound the main flow of use case?

On the other hand, to relieve this process or use case I realize that can be improved and then I put it as follows:

- Story: The Actor "A" examines the complaint and determines whether or not the claim REJECTS. To do so, use that system option titled "Reject Claim", pressing the System automatically makes a new request in the "inbox" of requests for "Reject" (not an e-mail box, but a form where all applications are displayed)

Questions:

Are they two use cases, ie, one for REQUEST and one to actually REJECT, or is a single use case with two actors, like "REJECT CLAIM"?
How would compound the main flow of use case?
This new "Inbox", which specifies, in a new use case?

Of course very grateful for your responses or contributions!

Comment: See There are two cases accept or reject and both are sub-case of request use case so u can include reject and accept as a sub-case  in request use case.@User1359768

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is what A and B actually want to do? In other words if their phone rang, what would they say why they have to cut the conversation short...

At first glance use-cases would then be:

A --> Examine Claim

B --> Expedite Rejection Letter

Or something along those lines. All other actions then become either steps in a use-case, an exception, etc.